# Javascript subclass code explanation

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I have this piece of code (from "Secrets of the Javascript Ninja"):

```
(function() {
  var initializing = false,
      superPattern = /xyz/.test(function() { xyz; }) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;

  Object.subClass = function(properties) {
    var _super = this.prototype;

    initializing = true;
    var proto = new this();
    initializing = false;    

    for (var name in properties) {

      proto[name] = typeof properties[name] == "function" &&
                    typeof _super[name] == "function"     && 
                    superPattern.test(properties[name])   ?
        (function(name, fn) {
          return function() {
            var tmp = this._super;

            this._super = _super[name];

            var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
            this._super = tmp;

            return ret;
          };
        })(name, properties[name])
        :
        properties[name];
    }

    function Class() {
      if (!initializing && this.init) {
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
      } 
    }  

    Class.prototype = proto;
    Class.constructor = Class;                // Why do we need this?
    Class.subClass = arguments.callee;        // Why is this not Object.subClass?
    return Class;

  };

})();

var Person = Object.subClass({
  init: function(isDancing) {
    this.dancing = isDancing;
    return true;
  },
  dance: function() {
    return this.dancing;
  }
});

var person = new Person(true);
alert (person.dance());
```

I am having a hard time understanding 2 things:

1. Why is `Class.constructor = Class`?

   Why do we need to override it at all? I tried commenting it out and it worked perfectly fine.
2. Why do we have `Class.subClass = arguments.callee`?

   I tried using `Class.subClass = Object.subClass` (which makes more sense?) and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I think your question just answered my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733249/ruby-code-blocks-versus-javascript-anonymous-functions-distiction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is `Class.constructor = Class`?

I don't know, it does not make any sense. It probably was supposed to be `proto.constructor = Class;`.

> Why do we have `Class.subClass = arguments.callee`? I tried using `Class.subClass = Object.subClass` (which makes more sense?) and it seems to work fine.

Yes, that's what he meant. `arguments.callee` is deprecated, but had the same effect. Your version is better.

You might also have a look at [Is John Resig's Javascript inheritance snippet deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15050816/1048572).