# In Javascript how do I automatically set properties to null if they don't exist?

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript class (using [John Resig's approach](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)) that I create an instance of and pass an `args` object, like so:

```
var myCucumber = new Cucumber({
   size: 'small'
   organic: true
})
```

Within the class itself, it references many properties on the `args` object. However none of the properties are meant to be mandatory, so there may be some missing ones at times, which causes "property is undefined" errors.

To remedy this, I do the following:

```
args.size = args.size || null;
args.organic = args.organic || false;
args.colour = args.colour || null;
args.origin = args.origin || null;
```

It seems kind of annoying to have to do this for each property that may get used throughout the class.

**Is there a clean way to assume that any property of args will be `null` if it hasn't been passed in when an instance of the class was created?**

Comment: Wherever you're using it, couldn't you just check for `undefined` instead, or both, or here's a crazy idea, just check for anything falsy ?

Comment: If you do want to use these properties, just initialize them with some initial values (or even null) in its constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest addding a function to handle values in the expected way.

Example:

```
Cucumber.prototype._args = function(attr) {
  return this.args[attr] || null;
}

// Then you may use it to access values as follows:
this._args('size');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few ways of doing it, however I would not use the Resig method, as it has problems in ES5 [Is John Resig's Javascript inheritance snippet deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050816/is-john-resigs-javascript-inheritance-snippet-deprecated)

1) (Resig) Create a constructor function and assign values to the all the properties that do not exist:

```
var Cucumber = Class.extend({
{ 
  init: function(args){
    this.size = null;
    this.organic = false;
    //etc
    for (var key in args.keys()) {
     this[key] = args[key];
    }
  },
}
```

2) second option use the [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) with descriptors. This provides you the ability to create object properties with default values.

```
// Example where we create an object with a couple of sample properties.
// (Note that the second parameter maps keys to *property descriptors*.)
o = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
  // foo is a regular 'value property'
  size: { writable: true, configurable: true, value: null },
});
```

3) simliarly use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)

I prefer the two later ways, it as I believe it's clear and better to use the Object.create / Object.defineProperty, here is some additional info on the matter:

http://jaxenter.com/a-modern-approach-to-object-creation-in-javascript-107304.html

[Understanding the difference between Object.create() and new SomeFunction()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
for (var key in args.keys()) {
    args[key] = args[key] || null;
}
```

This is because every object has a `keys()` function that returns an array of keys of that object.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Answer (score 0):

You can check if any of object attribute has already been set just before you refer it, like @adeneo suggested.

If your object has a long list of attributes, you can use @aliasm2k's solution.

Or you can write an object constructor function and use it. For example

```
function ToothPaste(color = null, flavor = null, amount = null){
  this.color = color;
  this.flavor = flavor;
  this.amount = amount;
}

var myTp = new ToothPaste('white');
alert(myTp.color);
alert(myTp.flavor);
alert(myTp.amount);
```