# Why does John Resig re-declare the original _super, after using inherited _super?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, resig

Taken from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052240/1487102

Scroll down to see the lines I'm curious about

It makes sense that he declares the inherited function `this._super` before applying

> What I don't get is: after he executes the function and gets the return val, why does he replace `this._super` with whatever it was beforehand??

The comment says that it only needs to be declared temporarily, but why would you not leave it declared?? I don't see how garbage collection would be improved, or any other optimization.

```
/* Simple JavaScript Inheritance for ES 5.1
 * based on http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/
 *  (inspired by base2 and Prototype)
 * MIT Licensed.
 */
(function(global) {
  "use strict";
  var fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;

  // The base Class implementation (does nothing)
  function BaseClass(){}

  // Create a new Class that inherits from this class
  BaseClass.extend = function(props) {
    var _super = this.prototype;

    // Set up the prototype to inherit from the base class
    // (but without running the init constructor)
    var proto = Object.create(_super);

    // Copy the properties over onto the new prototype
    for (var name in props) {
      // Check if we're overwriting an existing function
      proto[name] = typeof props[name] === "function" && 
        typeof _super[name] == "function" && fnTest.test(props[name])
        ? (function(name, fn){
            return function() {
              var tmp = this._super;

              // Add a new ._super() method that is the same method
              // but on the super-class
              this._super = _super[name];

              // The method only need to be bound temporarily, so we
              // remove it when we're done executing
              var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
```

> ```
>              this._super = tmp;  // <------ why??
> ```

```
              return ret;
            };
          })(name, props[name])
        : props[name];
    }

    // The new constructor
    var newClass = typeof proto.init === "function"
      ? proto.hasOwnProperty("init")
        ? proto.init // All construction is actually done in the init method
        : function SubClass(){ _super.init.apply(this, arguments); }
      : function EmptyClass(){};

    // Populate our constructed prototype object
    newClass.prototype = proto;

    // Enforce the constructor to be what we expect
    proto.constructor = newClass;

    // And make this class extendable
    newClass.extend = BaseClass.extend;

    return newClass;
  };

  // export
  global.Class = BaseClass;
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of confusion about what `this` was referring to

When declaring `this._super = function`, the entire class instance will have a key `_super`, which points to a specific function (obviously not desired)